# Ckeditor Popup panels overflow parent container

Tags: html, css, vue.js, ckeditor, ckeditor5

How do I make sure that the popup panels from the toolbar plugins do not overflow, and pop ups within the parent container, using CKEditor version 5 ???

see image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzJ2o.png

Tried fixing it with CSS, but doesn't seem to work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.